# Как отсортировать по приоритету mx записи вывод команды host

Tags: linux, bash

Нужно через `host` вывести mx-записи домена, чтобы они были отсортированы по приоритету. Если без сортировки, то все до боли просто

```sh
$ host -t mx [имя_домена]
```

А как сделать, чтоб выходил он отсортированный?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`host -t mx google.com | sort -k 6 -n`

Команда `sort -k 6 -n` сортирует по шестой колонке в выводе `mx` как числа.

Сортировать в обратном порядке `sort -k 6 -n -r`